# How to use flex to upload a swf file

Tags: php, apache-flex, actionscript-3, file-upload

I am trying to upload files to my server using a flex program but the swf files are not being uploaded. So I tried to upload other file types such as png, jpg, txt, xml and all of these upload without a problem but swf will not upload.

MXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        private function init():void {
            urlRequest = new URLRequest(serverSideScript);
            fileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList();
            fileReferenceList.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelectedHandler);
        }

        private function uploadFile():void {
            fileReferenceList.browse();
        }

        private function fileSelectedHandler(event:Event):void {
            var fileReference:FileReference;
            var fileReferenceList:FileReferenceList = FileReferenceList(event.target);
            var fileList:Array = fileReferenceList.fileList;

            // get the first file that the user chose
            fileReference = FileReference(fileList[0]);

            // upload the file to the server side script
            fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadCompleteHandler);
            fileReference.upload(urlRequest);

            // update the status text
            statusText.text = "Uploading...";
        }

        private function uploadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
            statusText.text = "File Uploaded: " + event.target.name;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label text="Upload File From Flex to PHP" fontWeight="bold"/>
<s:Label text="Choose a file..." id="statusText"/>
<s:Button click="uploadFile();" label="Upload File"/>
</s:Application>
```

PHP File:

```
<?php

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['Filedata']['size'];

move_uploaded_file($tempFile, "./" . $fileName);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it has nothing to do with flex at all. The problem that I was having is the max upload size in the php.ini file was set to 2mb and the file I was trying to upload was 5mb.